# (JavaScript) How to define images as a variable in phaser 3

Tags: javascript, optimization, phaser-framework

In my Phaser game, I have arrows define as a variable with the "let" keyword inside an if statement. I do this by displaying them as a sprite. However, I need to display the medals after the arrow hits the target. I also want the medals to display 30 px to the right of the previous medal, starting from the first medal displayed of course. What's the best way to do all of this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Video Game</title>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.11.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Configurations for the physics engine
    var physicsConfig = {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            debug: false //CHANGE THIS TO TRUE TO SEE LINES
        }
    }
    //Configurations for the game itself
    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        physics: physicsConfig,
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update,
            render: render
        }
    };
    //Start the game
    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    function preload ()
    {   
        //Images
        this.load.image('sky', 'assets/images/sky.png');
        this.load.image('target', 'assets/images/target.png');
        this.load.image('ground', 'assets/images/ground.png');
        this.load.image('arrow', 'assets/images/arrow.png');
        this.load.image('gold_medal', 'assets/images/goldmedal.png');
        this.load.image('silver_medal', 'assets/images/silvermedal.png');
        this.load.image('bronze_medal', 'assets/images/bronzemedal.png');
        //Spritesheets
        this.load.spritesheet('archer', 'assets/spritesheets/archer_sprites.png', {frameWidth: 128, frameHeight: 128});
        this.load.spritesheet('rings', 'assets/spritesheets/rings_sprite.png', {frameWidth: 320, frameHeight: 320});
        //Audio
        this.load.audio('arrow_shot', 'assets/sounds/arrow_shooting.mp3');
    }
    function create ()
    {   
        //Load all the images that won't move
        this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
        this.add.image(210, 200, 'ground');

        //Create the archer/player
        this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 410, 'archer');
        this.player.setBounce(0.2);
        this.player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

        //Shooting animation
        this.anims.create({
            key: 'shoot',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('archer', {start : 0, end: 4}),
            frameRate: 20,
            repeat: 0
        });

        //Rings animation
        this.anims.create({
            key: 'rings_anim',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('rings', {start : 0, end : 69}),
            frameRate: 10,
            repeat: 0
        })
        //Play the animation on start
        this.rings = this.physics.add.sprite(300, 40, 'rings');
        this.rings.anims.play('rings_anim', true);

        //Create the target
        this.target = this.physics.add.sprite(530, 365, 'target');
        this.target.setSize(115, 95).setOffset(70, 130); //TARGET HITBOX
        this.target.enableBody = true;
        this.target.setImmovable();

        //Create an array for arrows for later
        this.arrows = [];

        //Create an array for medals for later
        this.medals = [];

        //Get keypresses
        this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
        //Assign input for spacebar
        this.spacebar = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.SPACE);

        //Play sound when the arrow is shot
        this.arrowSound = this.sound.add('arrow_shot');

        //Make the arrows collide with the target
        this.physics.add.collider(this.arrows, this.target)
    }
    function update ()
    {   
        //Declare constants for movement
        const playerMoveAmt = 200;
        const arrowMoveAmt = 1500;
        this.player.setDrag(2000);

        //Rotation of the player
        if (this.cursors.up.isDown && this.player.angle > -45) {
            this.player.angle -= 1;}

        if (this.cursors.down.isDown && this.player.angle < 0) {
            this.player.angle += 1;}

        //Shooting with the spacebar
        if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.spacebar)) {

            //Animate the shooting
            this.player.anims.play('shoot', true);

            //Arrow shooting
            let arrow = this.physics.add.sprite(this.player.x, (this.player.y + 20), 'arrow');
            arrow.enableBody = true;
            arrow.body.immovable = false;

            //Edit arrow hitbox 
            arrow.setSize(50, 15).setOffset(5, 50);

            arrow.setGravityY(3600); //Gravity will affect the arrows

            //Arrow speeds
            arrow.setVelocityX(arrowMoveAmt);
            arrow.setVelocityY((this.player.angle * 50));

            this.arrows.push(arrow); //Add arrow to the arrow created earlier
            this.arrowSound.play(); //Play the sound
        }

        else if(this.target.body.touching.left) {

            //Loop to create multiple arrows
            for (i = 0; i < this.arrows.length; i += 1) {
                newarrows = this.arrows[i];
                newarrows.setGravityY(0);
                newarrows.setVelocityX(0);
                newarrows.setVelocityY(0);
                //Reset the player angle for difficulty
                this.player.angle = 0;
                //Gold medal
                if (410 < newarrows.y && newarrows.y < 435) {
                    let goldMedal = this.add.image(300, 200, 'gold_medal');
                    goldMedal;
                }
                //Silver medal
                else if (395 < newarrows.y && newarrows.y < 450) { 
                    this.add.image(300, 200, 'silver_medal');
                }
                //Bronze medal
                else if (380 < newarrows.y && newarrows.y < 460) {
                    this.add.image(300, 200, 'bronze_medal');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function render() {
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried doing this by using "if (newArrows.length == 5)" and "if (this.arrows.length == 5)". I also tried defining the image as a variable and calling it to display, then pushing it to an array, like with the arrow.

Hope all of this makes sense

Comment: Hi @Robert Smith, do you need everytime the arrow hits the target a new medals shows up `30px` to the right?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal yes, the corresponding medal, with a max of 5 medals

Comment: One last question, a max of 5 medals of  each type or 5 medals max total without distinction between bronze, silve and gold?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal 5 medals max total

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Manuel Abascal thank you!! Will try when I get home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution:

- **First**, I changed the **`for` loop** that I did previously to a **`while` loop** since it's better for this use case.
- **Second**, I created a variable, before the **`while` loop** named **`arrowOnTargetPositionX`** & set the initial value to **`200`**.
- **Third**, I set the variable to its own value + 30(like the same numbers of pixels that you wanted).
- **Four**, I removed the **`if else` statement logic** from the loop & created a **`function`** named **`getMedal(arrowOnTargetPositionX);**`.
- **Fith**, I declared the **`function`** below & passed the parameter value to update the position horizontally of the new medals.

**Finally**, this is the result code:

```
function update ()
{   
    //Declare constants for movement
    const playerMoveAmt = 200;
    const arrowMoveAmt = 1500;
    this.player.setDrag(2000); 

    //Rotation of the player
    if (this.cursors.up.isDown && this.player.angle > -45) {
        this.player.angle -= 1;}

    if (this.cursors.down.isDown && this.player.angle < 0) {
        this.player.angle += 1;}

    //Shooting with the spacebar
    if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.spacebar)) {

        //Animate the shooting
        this.player.anims.play('shoot', true);

        //Arrow shooting
        let arrow = this.physics.add.sprite(this.player.x, (this.player.y + 20), 'arrow');
        arrow.enableBody = true;
        arrow.body.immovable = false;

        //Edit arrow hitbox 
        arrow.setSize(50, 15).setOffset(5, 50);

        arrow.setGravityY(3600); //Gravity will affect the arrows

        //Arrow speeds
        arrow.setVelocityX(arrowMoveAmt);
        arrow.setVelocityY((this.player.angle * 50));

        this.arrows.push(arrow); //Add arrow to the arrow created earlier
        this.arrowSound.play(); //Play the sound
    }

    else if(this.target.body.touching.left) {
        let i = 0;

        // Set initial horizontal position of new medals
        let arrowOnTargetPositionX = 200;

        //Loop to create multiple arrows
        while (i < this.arrows.length) {
            newArrows = this.arrows[i];
            newArrows.setGravityY(0);
            newArrows.setVelocityX(0);
            newArrows.setVelocityY(0);

            // Add 30 to new medals horizontal position
            arrowOnTargetPositionX = arrowOnTargetPositionX + 30;

            // Calls the function to get medal & passed the variable as an argument
            getMedal(arrowOnTargetPositionX);

            i++;
        }
    }

    // function to get different medals
    getMedal = (value) => {
        //Gold medal
        if (410 < newArrows.y && newArrows.y < 435) {
            this.add.image(value, 180, 'gold_medal');
        }
        //Silver medal
        else if (395 < newArrows.y && newArrows.y < 450) { 
            this.add.image(value, 250, 'silver_medal');
        }
        //Bronze medal
        else if (380 < newArrows.y && newArrows.y < 460)  {
            this.add.image(value, 320, 'bronze_medal'); 
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

For displaying only a max of 5 medals, use this code snippet:

```
//Loop to create multiple arrows
while (i < this.arrows.length) {
    newArrows = this.arrows[i];
    newArrows.setGravityY(0);
    newArrows.setVelocityX(0);
    newArrows.setVelocityY(0);

    // Add 30 to new medals horizontal position
    arrowOnTargetPositionX = arrowOnTargetPositionX + 30;

    if(this.arrows.length <= 5) {
        // Calls the function to get medal & passed the variable as an argument
        getMedal(arrowOnTargetPositionX);
    }

    i++;
}
```